# Posting Textarea to Controller (currently null is being passed) - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, controller

I'm creating a website where the user will fill in a textarea (in response to a question) and then press next. When they press next, the textarea will be submitted to the controller and the next question will be retrieved (I'll also store the answer in a cookie). Unfortunately, when I run the code in debug I've realized that the textarea is not being submitted b/c the parameter is null. I've tried to figure it out and I've looked around and I seem to be doing it properly. Hopefully it's an easy fix. Thanks so much for your time!

**Controller:**

```
// POST: /Question/1 
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult q(string textAnswer) {
    if (textAnswer != null)
        ViewBag.current++;

    Question q = db.Questions.Find(ViewBag.current);
    if (q == null) {
        return RedirectToAction("submit");
    }

    return View(q);
}
```

**View:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="myForm" method="post" enctype="text/plain" name="input">

    <p>
        <h3>Question <span id="integer">@ViewBag.current</span></h3>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Ques)
    </p>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Answer</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <textarea rows="20" style="width:600px" id="textAnswer"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls" >
            <button onclick="history.back()" type="button" class="btn">Back</button>
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Next" />
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: <textarea rows="20" style="width:600px" id="textAnswer" name="textAnswer"></textarea>

Comment: Try adding a normal input element with a name and see if that gets posted.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your textarea needs a name in order to be posted.

```
<textarea rows="20" style="width:600px" id="textAnswer" name="textAnswer"></textarea>
```

Also remove the enctype attribute from your form.

Comment: I modified my code and it's still passing Null for some reason... I tried changing the name of the form as well and the textarea is still not getting passed. Thanks a lot for the prompt response!

Comment: Try removing your `enctype` attribute. I suggest this only becasue I have never specified that attribute unless I am trying to post file data.

Answer (score 2):

Text areas don't post strings, they post **string arrays**. 
Your controller should have this signature:

```
public ActionResult q(string[] textAnswer)
```